# Facebook: Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration

Tags: facebook, oauth

Starting this weekend a number of our older Facebook games are failing to load. I believe this is an issue caused by the game not getting an access token, and thus not able to make calls on behalf of the user (i.e. /me, etc.). I am seeing the following in the Javascript console:

**Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.**

Afterwards I get this error, which I believe is related:

**NetworkError: 400 Bad Request - graph.facebook.com/me?fields=locale**

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }
}
```

The strange part is that none of these games have been touched for months. So that leads me to think that Facebook changed something with their API. I did an extensive search here and on search engines and was not able to find anything with a solution. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are using a stale version of the JS SDK, which references an old, blacklisted resource.

Please always use the copy as served from connect.facebook.net.