# WP plugin issue - Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

I have a Premium SEO Pack – Wordpress Plugin installed and with its Facebook planner, we are supposed to  authorize app after providing the initial settings.

I have provided all the settings correctly. Provide app id, app secret, app domain, site url (through add platform), settings->advanced->enabled browser oAuth login, provided Valid oAuth redirect URI http://example.org/psp_seo_fb_oauth .

But still I get the "Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains." error.

Also its not on localhost, but production server.

Comment: It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or is the domain a subdomain of one of the App's domains - and does that check out against the registered url? Can you post link for what you have looked at?

Comment: I have checked this https://www.facebook.com/help/community/question/?id=542958419109491 , this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20690174/facebook-login-throws-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration , this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13317207/facebook-given-url-is-not-allowed-by-the-application-configuration and many such similar on stackoverflow.@Steve

Comment: "Embedded browser OAuth Login" seemed to have capital O - could that make a difference?

Comment: website url is http://example.org/ , oauth redirect url is http://example.org/psp_seo_fb_oauth , example.org added in app domains , add platform->site url included http://example.org/ . So there's no subdomain. @Steve

Comment: Sorry for wasting your time - the links look like they had happily solved it didn't they!

Comment: I did not understand your last comment, what about the capital 'O' @Steve . No, despite putting all the correct addresses everywhere, that problem is still there.

Comment: your info said `settings->advanced->enabled browser oAuth login`  may only have been a typo in the post. Sorry I can only wish you best of luck.

Comment: ok, thanks, hope someone else would help me on stackoverflow

Comment: OAuth is the same as oAuth? Or is that not the original code. Sorry to have disappeared abruptly this morning - end of my shift.

Comment: OAuth stands for “Open Authorization.” and written that way. https://www.empowerid.com/learningcenter/standards/oauth

Comment: I suspect about ssl being mandatory to use facebook app.. couldn't locate any info page like this from the facebook dev site though yet..

Comment: Any use? https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/facebook_ssl_oauth.html  Quote:Facebook announces that as of October 1st, 2015, all websites called from Facebook will have to be secured with SHA256-signed SSL certificates. The company then complies with the CA/B Forum recommandations, forbidding the use of SHA1 certificates after 2017.

Facebook Will Stop Supporting SHA-1 in October

Comment: Thanks. it doesn't clear though, if its applicable even though the website is using facebook app only to post content. In other words app is not going to ask other poeple to login to their facebook account. its the website/app's own account they would be using to post the content in their groups.

Comment: Sorry - just thought it might indicate that they had changed the rules and not let anyone know that OAuth wasn't quite so open any more either. Best of luck with your quest!  Is this the one? https://wordpress.org/plugins/premium-seo-pack-light-version/installation/

Comment: Probably a stupid question but have you  signed up to their website and posted on there? There seem to be a lot of issues surrounding OAuth in WordPress. e.g. https://wordpress.org/support/topic/issue-with-oauth

Comment: Is the app's account on an `https://` url? Seems to be the way everything is headed! http://www.wired.com/2014/04/https/

Comment: Item about `redirect_uri` By @David Alpert got lots of upvotes on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13733506/facebook-one-or-more-of-the-given-urls-is-not-allowed-by-the-apps-settings?rq=1   Sorry looks like I am wrong about https according to some of those posts!

Comment: thanks @Steve for your efforts, but I already have tried everything they seem to suggest. Basically everything revolves around few basic settings like adding domain under settings->basic->App domains, add platform->wesbite->site url, settings->advanced->client OAuth settings->Valid OAuth redirect URI

Comment: Although this one https://wordpress.org/support/topic/more-facebook-troubles is good. I missed to go through this support system here. I am going to explore this now to every last thread on fb OAuth issue of there are any. But I already started believing it could also be a bug in their own code unless I am missing something very obvious.

Comment: Also worth going directly onto the plugin's support forum as the author seems active in responding to queries if it is the plugin I asked about above.

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-php-sdk-v4/issues/473  Has several comments surrounding oAuth which seem to suggest that documentation may not be entirely accurate. hope you solved it.